# How to make a Cisco AP1142N speak Bonjour?

Tags: cisco, wifi, ios, multicast, bonjour

I have an autonomous Cisco access point (model AP1142N) and an Apple TV that are on the same physical and logical network. Bonjour does not work across the access point — both WiFi-to-WiFi and Wired-to-Wired seem to work, but as soon as multicast traffic has to pass the access point, it is dropped.

There are many different (sometimes contradictory) purported solutions to that problem on the Cisco forums, here's just an excerpt:

- [*Deactivate IGMP snooping on all interfaces*](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2014818)
- [*Enable IGMP snooping on the access point*](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2164488)
- [*iOS v15 has broken Bonjour*](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2200843)

I tried all suggestions that I could find, activated and deactivated IGMP snooping on all combinations of interfaces, but to no avail. It didn't matter whether I used iOS v12 or v15.

There is a lot of material for the lightweight (controller-based) version of this access point, but a lot less for the autonomous one.

I don't really know what to make of all this — right now I'm just curious if anyone has had any success at all in getting Bonjor to work with autonomous Cisco access points.

Thanks for any feedback!

*Update*:
I just noticed that Bonjour works fine for iOS devices (tested with an iPhone 5 and an iPad Mini) on the same exact WiFi network! Now I am really stumped — I would figure that it either works for both OSes or none...

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a Cisco doc on this exact topic (AppleTV) but it is for the lightweight version.  Might help you though:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/wireless/ps4570/products_tech_note09186a0080bb1d7c.shtml

The things you have to do are still the same.

Comment: Many thanks for that link. Like you say, most of the information is only applicable if you have a controller-based version. The section on creating a Bonjour Gateway looks interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears after some research that there are two layers of IGMP snooping that need to be disabled and most documents only give one. The two commands you need to execute are:

```
no ip igmp snooping 
no dot11 igmp snooping-helper
```

Most examples just give the former. You may need to disconnect and reconnect the clients afterwards.

Credit needs to be given to this site:

http://www.md3v.com/cisco-wireless-access-points-and-the-google-chromecast

Which provided the same resolution for a Chromecast issue.